# How do the w32Time service get the time?

Tags: windows-10, bios, time

We have a Problem on a PC with Windows 10(new installation, reinstalled and refreshed), to make updates the PC was also online.

But also offline, the Time is changing randomly to a Date in the Future and Past, independently from the time in BIOS. Why this happens ?

Maybe the Time Service can be controlled, on how it get the Time.

In the Picture below it looks like the Time service is collecting, synchronizing and adjusting the time from different sources.

Maybe I will try to Debug the Time Service, with the win32Time-tool and maybe with WinDbg too.

[image]

[Source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/windows-time-service/how-the-windows-time-service-works)

Comment: Perhaps you should ask about your actual problem instead. You’re asking an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Edit, I try to figure out, why the Time changes randomly(offline or online), also when I adjust the Time again,

Comment: Anything related logged in the System event log?

Answer (score 0):

The W32Time service is implemented in a dynamic link library called W32Time.dll, which is installed by default in %Systemroot%\System32.

W32Time.dll support a specification by the Kerberos V5 authentication protocol that required clocks on a network to be synchronized. Starting with Windows Server 2003, W32Time.dll provided increased accuracy in network clock synchronization over the Windows Server 2000 operating system.

The Windows Time service uses NTP to help synchronize time across a network. NTP is an Internet time protocol that includes the discipline algorithms necessary for synchronizing clocks. NTP is a more accurate time protocol than the Simple Network Time Protocol (SNTP) that is used in some versions of Windows; however, W32Time continues to support SNTP to enable backward compatibility with computers running SNTP-based time services

Sources:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/windows-time-service/windows-time-service-tech-ref#where-to-find-windows-time-service-configuration-related-information